# Rails TimeZone issue - Group query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, timezone

I have my server in `NYC` and the data in PostgreSQL is stored in `UTC` but all my data on the presentational layer is to be shown in `IST`

I have the following settings done

**config/application.rb**

```
config.time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local # Or :utc
```

When doing a query i am doing the following

```
Influencer.where(created_at: DateTime.now.in_time_zone-(days-1).days..DateTime.now.in_time_zone).group("created_at::date").count
```

but because of the grouping i am still not able to get the right data segmented by the required timezone.

What is the Problem?

On `Jan 3rd` - X signups `IST`
On `Jan 4th` - Y signups `IST`

but the `Y - Z` which happened in the timezone difference is being added to X when i run a above query.

Any pointers on how to handle this?

Comment: what do you mean by "not able to get the right data". what do you expect and what do you get instead? show examples

Comment: @emaillenin will update the data

Comment: I am getting the proper dates in the result with the same configuration